# How to unbuffer cut?

Tags: pipe, cut

I want to get just e-mail addresses that end in "@xyz.nl" from my mail logfile. To achieve this I do:

```
# tail -f /var/log/mail.log | grep --i --line-buffered "@xyz.nl" | cut -d '@' -f 1 | cut -d '<' -f 2
```

The --line-buffered with grep is necessary because it will otherwise buffer its output because the pipe is not considered a terminal. Grep will output lines like these:

```
Aug 29 11:56:01 localhost postfix/smtp[4124]: 05491500123: to=<someone@xyz.nl>, relay=123.456.123.456[123.456.123.456]:25, delay=2, delays=0.4/0/0.4/1.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 u7T9twxN074009 Message accepted for delivery)
```

The first cut then makes:

```
Aug 29 11:56:01 localhost postfix/smtp[4124]: 05491500123: to=<someone
```

The second cut should generate:

```
someone
```

However it seems that cut is also buffering. If I start the command with **cat** instead of **tail -f** I get all relevant results (in the prefered format) from the log file. But I need the results from the log file in real time.

I tried using unbuffer for this:

```
# tail -f /var/log/mail.log | grep --i --line-buffered "@xyz.nl" | unbuffer cut -d '@' -f 1 | cut -d '<' -f 2
```

Also tried:

```
# unbuffer tail -f /var/log/mail.log | grep --i --line-buffered "@xyz.nl" | unbuffer cut -d '@' -f 1 | cut -d '<' -f 2
```

...which should remove the 4K buffering from the first **cut**. However, this doesn't work. I know it is buffering because if I grep for our local domain it gets a lot more hits, the buffer is filled sooner and output is generated earlier (in 4K batches).

So my question is: how do I unbuffer **cut**?

Related: I know sed and (g)awk can deliver the e-mail addresses to me. I have been trying but as yet without any result. Answers using sed or (g)awk are welcome and may solve my direct issue but I remain interested in the nominal answer of the question how to unbuffer the cut command. The cut command doesn't speak of (un)buffering.

Comment: `awk -F'[><@]' '/@xyz.nl/ {print $2}'`...

Comment: try `grep -oP '[^<]+(?=@xyz.nl)'` (along with your other grep options as needed)

Comment: Both the awk and grep options above work like a charm!

Comment: Still unanswered: Why does’t `unbuffer` work here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you're on a system using GNU Coreutils (almost any Linux), you can try `stdbuf`:

```
… | stdbuf -oL cut -d '@' -f 1 | …
```

`-oL` makes it line buffered, which seems like what you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Does not change anything for me for some reason. :(

Comment: @panzi Feel free to ask your own question, linking to this one. Please include full details (exact command you're running if possible, OS, distro, and version, etc.) Hopefully someone will be able to figure out why it doesn't work for you.