# How to correctly unbuffer a pipeline?

Tags: shell, pipe, buffer

I'm trying to follow various answers in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe), [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/294218/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-without-buffering-on-unix-linux/589614) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307387/how-to-unbuffer-cut) threads, but my pipeline still appears buffered. Here's an example attempt:

```
unbuffer sh -c 'echo -n test; sleep 1; echo; sleep 1; echo -n hello; sleep 1; echo' | grep .
```

The above command should immediately print `test`, then after on second print `hello`, and after one more second end. Instead, I get a one-second delay, only then `test`, then, after a *two*-second delay, `hello` with command exit.

Note that here I'm trying to *completely* get rid of buffering, and `--line-buffered` option of `grep` won't help. So, how do I truly unbuffer this pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` will output the *lines* that match a pattern, so it can't output anything until a full line (or end-of-file upon which, if the last line was not terminated, the behaviour varies depending on the implementation) has been read.

So in:

```
(echo -n foo; sleep 1; echo bar) | grep .
```

It's not because `echo` *buffers its output*. It doesn't. How could it, once it has terminated? It's because `grep` is waiting for the end of the line (that will come, immediately followed by end-of-file with the second `echo`).

To do what you seem to want, you'd need to read lines with a timeout for each line like (with `bash`):

```
(echo -n foo; sleep 1; echo bar) |
  while true; do
    TMOUT=0.1 IFS= read -r line; ret=$?
    if [ "$(kill -l "$ret")" = ALRM ]; then
      [ -n "$line" ] || continue
      ors=
    elif [ "$ret" -eq 0 ]; then
      ors=$'\n'
    elif [ -z "$line" ]; then
      break
    fi
    [[ $line =~ . ]] && printf %s "$line$ors"
  done
```

(you get a pass in the loop at least every 0.1 second).