# How is the default stdout buffering set?

Tags: pipe, tail, buffer

Running on Red Hat EL7, we have these great long lines in our log files so I do a

```
tail -f Log | cut -c1-$COLUMNS
```

This works great on some systems but other--apparently identical--systems, the pipe holds the data until the buffer is full.  As I was typing this, SE gave me [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307387/how-to-unbuffer-cut) answer which when used:

```
tail -f Log | stdbuf -oL cut -c1-$COLUMNS
```

does what I need but I'd like to know what is different. I'd like the systems to run the same, good or bad.

Is there a default buffering that has been set?  How was it set and where?

Update:
I opened two windows into a system where the problem occurs and tried:

```
while date; do usleep 500000 ; done | cut -c1-100
```

and got no output (until the buffer is full).  In the other window, I ran strace on the cut process and got an endless series of:

```
read(0, "Wed Oct 26 13:04:12 CDT 2022\n", 4096) = 29
read(0, "Wed Oct 26 13:04:12 CDT 2022\n", 4096) = 29
read(0, "Wed Oct 26 13:04:13 CDT 2022\n", 4096) = 29
read(0, "Wed Oct 26 13:04:13 CDT 2022\n", 4096) = 29
read(0, "Wed Oct 26 13:04:14 CDT 2022\n", 4096) = 29
read(0, "Wed Oct 26 13:04:14 CDT 2022\n", 4096) = 29
read(0, "Wed Oct 26 13:04:15 CDT 2022\n", 4096) = 29
```

I think that's pretty conclusive evidence that the cut is doing the buffering.  But how does it decide to do so?

Comment: Which one do you mean, the output of `tail` or the output of `cut? Because in what you're showing, `tail -f` is the only one writing to a pipe, and AFAIK it shouldn't do buffering.

Comment: Any difference between your systems regarding /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size ?

Comment: @MC68020, I never heard of it but the values are the same everywhere: 1048576

Comment: @Ilkkachu All I can do is speculate about who is doing the buffering.  I assumed it was the pipe but I believe pipes don’t work that way.  The `stdbuf` command makes the data come out immediately on the systems where the problem occurs. Since the `stdbuf` precedes the `cut`, I assume the cut is doing the buffering.

Answer (score 1):

The usual behaviour is that output to a terminal is line-buffered, and anything else is block-buffered.  See e.g. the [GNU glibc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Buffering-Concepts.html):

> Newly opened streams are normally fully buffered, with one exception: a stream connected to an interactive device such as a terminal is initially line buffered. [...]

So something like

```
grep ... | cut ...
```

would have *`grep`* buffer its output, but not `cut`. You'd fix that by running `stdbuf -o0 grep ...` (or `grep --line-buffered`) instead. Or using one of the many other workarounds, see: [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)

On the other hand, `tail -f` shouldn't buffer its output.

Of course, that doesn't fit with what you said about using `stdbuf -oL` on *`cut`* fixing it; it should be line-buffering its output already. If it's going to a terminal, that is. If you had `| cut ... > somefile` that would be different.